# Console Application crashes without exception when using certain startup?

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

I'm using Selenium, I make many calls to `INavigation`'s `GoToUrl` method throghout the application. The second call causes it to crash the application, or exit with exit code 0, no exception given.

It's got path for execution, I've attached a debugger to the exact line, even running through immediate window also crashes it.

I've since understood that its because of my usage of https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline and letting it handle the execution, although why is this happening? Is it a bug of the package?

Option A - Works fine (no crash)

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, collection) => ServiceCollection.AddServices(collection, context.Configuration))
        .Build();

    var commandHandler = host.Services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandler>();
    var options = new BasicReportOptions()
    {
        UrlsToCheckFile = "...",
        DuplicateUrlsToCheckFile = "...",
        FocusedPhrasesFile = "...",
    };
    await commandHandler.HandleBasicReport(options);
}
```

Option B - Doesn't work (crashes) with the difference being the call to `CommandHandler`'s `HandleInputAsync` (below) being called instead of the actual method.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, collection) => ServiceCollection.AddServices(collection, context.Configuration))
        .Build();

    var commandHandler = host.Services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandler>();
    await commandHandler.HandleInputAsync(args);
}
```

`HandleInputAsync`:

```
public async Task HandleInputAsync(string[] args)
{
    Parser.Default.ParseArguments<BasicReportOptions, ExtensiveReportOptions>(args)
        .WithParsed<BasicReportOptions>(async options => await HandleBasicReport(options))
        .WithParsed<ExtensiveReportOptions>(async options => await HandleExtensiveReport(options));
}
```

So it seems to me that, when using `HandleInputAsync` and calling the methods without `WithParsed`, causes calls to Selenium's IWebDriver to crash?

Comment: Sure. `throw new Exception("testing");` seems to throw an exception. No exception is being thrown for my issue. It's simply just halting execution.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid my question is, why is the usage of (https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline), causing sequential calls to internal Selenium methods to exit execution of my main process, which I feel I've made fairly clear.

Comment: @devlincarnate as I've said, no exception is being thrown. Execution is simply ending without an exception.

Comment: @devlincarnate As I also said, I've put a breakpoint on the exact line, trying it via the debugger and immediate window, both seem to halt execution with no signs of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically gotta use `MapResult` of the package, it handles async better

```
public async Task HandleInputAsync(string[] args)
{
    await Parser.Default.ParseArguments<BasicReportOptions, ExtensiveReportOptions>(args)
        .MapResult(
            (BasicReportOptions opts) => HandleBasicReport(opts),
            (ExtensiveReportOptions opts) => HandleExtensiveReport(opts),
            errs => Task.FromResult(0));
}
```